# How to use setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed correctly?

Tags: ios, push

I used the `setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to hide `tabBar` when A `viewController` pushed to B `viewController`,but in the process ,the `navigationBar` displayed black background color and then became normal quickly.

I have spent a day to trying to solve this problem,but all ways not working.

Appreciating your help.

Thank you.

I just created a very simple "Tabbed Application" project like this.
[image]
Pust to viewController when clicked push barButtonItem,and the "Hide Bottom Bar On Push " property of viewController was checked in storyboard.

[image]

The result was :
[image]

Comment: - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    [segue.destinationViewController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
}

Comment: Show more code about how you setting up the A and B please.

Comment: I just created a new "Tabbed Application" project with Xcode(Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a)) , there was two tabs in it defaultly.And I added a barButtonItem at first viewcontroller for pushing to a new viewController that was checked "Hide Buttom Bar on Push" in storyboard.I didn't written other code anymore. @WorldOfWarcraft ,you can have a try.

Comment: I have uploaded pictures and described the proecss.@WorldOfWarcraft

Comment: Try to set the navigationBar's backgroundColor to whiteColor

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem while using old MacBook (about 2011 early) before. I think it is the ***render*** issue of the simulator while using some out-of-dated devices. But actually, when you run your code on real device （iPhone 5 above）, this issue is unusual.

Comment: My MacBook was made in this year.It happend the same problem while running my code on real device (iPhone 5) or iOS simulator(iPhone 5 above).This problem has confused me some days.

Comment: @wensj I have no idea yet.